# Make multiple menus work sequentially

Tags: menu, multiple-screens

I am working on simple point-of-sale (POS) software for a cafe.
I have to accomodate 3 selection options:

1. Selecting current sale user needs. Some sales can be saved for later use.
   [image]
2. Table catering to. (Maybe in a side menu.) This will again open a fresh new page to add to the specific table.
3. Nutrition type. (Food, Drink, Dessert, etc.) They open up pages with pictures of foods, drinks, etc for the user to select.

   Maybe somthing like this:
   [image]
   So user will select a sales instance (Current sale), then a table(Table1), Then Food from food menu, Select a food and save. But since all menus are available, customer can change midway the sales process

What I need: I need to provide a seamless way to get the user to select one option from each of the three menus and finish the sale, while keeping the option to change properties midway. (For example, change the customer table midway through the order.)

Answer (score 1):

**What you are describing is a process, and generally speaking, processes aren't found in a "main navigation".**

Looking at your main navigation bar (I'm assuming that's what the top area represents) I have to say I've got no idea what "1" means, why a timestamp is in the same area, and what the + and - buttons relate to. They seem like tabs that are supposed to relate to the content underneath, but they don't?

Perhaps it's because there's a mix of things going on in the main menu. It seems like you've got the process steps there, as well as the values entered during each step, and a way to alter them? I could be wrong, again, it's not really clear at first glance.

If you're taking a user through a process, show it as such. There's plenty of ways to this; previous/next buttons, a selection of buttons named after each step in the process (along the top, bottom or side of the app) where each step is highlighted as you're working on it, or you could toss everything into one big form, if that doesn't overload the UI.

The points I'm trying to make is that relationship is important, and that a process should be shown as a process, even if you can navigate it.

*On a side-note, maybe you should look at the finer details of the process. There are reasons why people pick "what they want" before filling out the billing details. The same reasons might apply to entering the table number last.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dirk,
As for the snapshot, it is from another software. 
The top menu in the snapshot shows instances of sales saved for later.
The tabs are numbered, and the time is time of orders starting maybe?!.

I just need a way for the three menus to be simultaeously be available to the user as he goes on to finish the order.
One menu above, one maybe as a side nav, and the other maybe as buttons.